# Set my website as default search engine in BB10Browser and Create opensearch plugin for BB10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, opensearch

I want to add my website in Default Search Engine option in **BB10 Browser** but on opening the website it is not showing the "**add search**" option. Is there any changes that have been done in BB10 browser from BB7 ?

Is it possible to make an opensearch plugin for **Blackberry 10 Browser** ?

If not then How to achieve above ?

Comment: Looks like its predefined by RIM.
The last post on this link might help
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-PlayBook/I-want-to-use-my-own-search-engine/td-p/1627713

Comment: As described in "http://helpblog.blackberry.com/2011/08/blackberry-7-tips/" we can do what I want in BB7 browser but I wonder about BB10 browser....and No, the link given by @Turdnugget does not answer my question.